# Multiple logins in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-1.2

In my current project in cakephp, there are different roles for different users like admin, developer, researcher and customers. Obviously, their views are also different depending on their usergroup..
But now my admin wants to be able to see the views for every usergroup in his browser. He has asked me to add two buttons on his home page for customer view and researcher view. Is this possible to achieve? And if yes, how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply override the role in the Auth session and reload the page? Here is a simple example.

```
public function toggle_user($role = 'reviewer') {
    $this->Session->write('Auth.User.role', $role);
    $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```

Change it depending on how your app is built.